# Java Math Server - Client side issues

Tags: java, netbeans, network-programming, client-server

Im making a simple Math Server for a project but im coming into some difficulties, when calculating the result. I have created the Math server but i know my problems are coming from the client side.

I have 4 classes, Math Service:

```
public interface MathService {
 public double add(double firstValue, double secondValue);
 public double sub(double firstValue, double secondValue);
 public double div(double firstValue, double secondValue);
 public double mul(double firstValue, double secondValue);
}
```

PlainMathService:

```
public class PlainMathService implements MathService {
 public double add(double firstValue, double secondValue) {
 return firstValue+secondValue;
 }
 public double sub(double firstValue, double secondValue) {
 return firstValue-secondValue;
 }
 public double mul(double firstValue, double secondValue) {
 return firstValue * secondValue;
 }
 public double div(double firstValue, double secondValue) {
 if (secondValue != 0)
 return firstValue / secondValue;
 return Double.MAX_VALUE;
 }
}
```

MathServer

```
    public class MathServer{
 protected MathService mathService;
 protected Socket socket;

 public void setMathService(MathService mathService) {
 this.mathService = mathService;
 }
 public void setSocket(Socket socket) {
 this.socket = socket;
 }
 public void execute() {
 try {
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
 new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
 // read the message from client and parse the execution
 String line = reader.readLine();
 double result = parseExecution(line);
 // write the result back to the client
 BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
 new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
 writer.write(""+result);
 writer.newLine();
 writer.flush();
 // close the stream
 reader.close();
 writer.close();
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
 }
 // the predefined protocol for the math operation is
 // operator:first value:second value
 protected double parseExecution(String line)
 throws IllegalArgumentException {
 double result = Double.MAX_VALUE;
 String [] elements = line.split(":");
 if (elements.length != 3)
 throw new IllegalArgumentException("parsing error!");
 double firstValue = 0;
 double secondValue = 0;
 try {
 firstValue = Double.parseDouble(elements[1]);
 secondValue = Double.parseDouble(elements[2]);
 }
 catch(Exception e) {
 throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid arguments!");
 }
 switch (elements[0].charAt(0)) {
 case '+':
 result = mathService.add(firstValue, secondValue);
 break;
 case '-':

 result = mathService.sub(firstValue, secondValue);
 break;
 case '*':
 result = mathService.mul(firstValue, secondValue);
 break;
 case '/':
 result = mathService.div(firstValue, secondValue);
 break;
 default:
 throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid math operation!");
 }
 return result;
 }
 public static void main(String [] args)throws Exception{
 int port = 80;
 if (args.length == 1) {
 try {
 port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
 }
 catch(Exception e){
 }
 }
 System.out.println("Math Server is running...");
 // create a server socket and wait for client’s connection
 ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
 Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
 // run a math server that talks to the client
 MathServer mathServer = new MathServer();
 mathServer.setMathService(new PlainMathService());
 mathServer.setSocket(socket);
 mathServer.execute();
 System.out.println("Math Server is closed...");
     }
   }
```

and finally, MathClient:

```
public class MathClient {
 public static void main(String [] args){
 String hostname = "localhost";
 int port = 80;
 if (args.length != 2) {
 System.out.println("Use the default setting...");
 }
 else {
     hostname = args[0];
 port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
 }
 try {
 // create a socket
 Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, 4444);

   // object creation handling keyboaard inputs
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(System.in));


 String Choice = "a",                    // variable
    firstValue = "45",      // 1st number
    secondValue = "2",      // 2nd number
    defoper = "-",      // default operation
    strResult="";
    // insntiate objects needed to send/receive to/from server
    InputStream in = socket.getInputStream(); //data read from socket
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in)); //add 
to buffer
    OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream(); //send data to socket
    PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(out, true); //send text

// operations
while (Choice.charAt(0) != 'x')
{
// ui
System.out.println("\n\n      E(x)it from server.\n" +
     "      Press any other key to calculate.  ");
Choice = input.readLine();
if (Choice.equals(""))
     Choice = "a";
switch(Choice.charAt(0))
{
     case 'x':
             pr.println("x");
             break;
     default:
             pr.println("a");
             System.out.print("Enter 1st integer: ");
             firstValue = input.readLine();
             if (firstValue.equals(""))
                     firstValue = "12";
                     System.out.print("Enter 2nd integer: ");
             secondValue = input.readLine();
             if (secondValue.equals(""))
                     secondValue = "2000";
                     System.out.print("Enter your operand: ");
             defoper = input.readLine();
             if (defoper.equals(""))
                     defoper = "+";
             // send the two numbers and the operation to server
             pr.println(firstValue);
             pr.println(secondValue);
             pr.println(defoper);
// read result from server
strResult = br.readLine();
System.out.println(strResult);
             break;
}
}
// close connection
socket.close();
}


 catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }}}
```

The problem is basically i can enter in the 1st and 2nd integer, and also the opperand, but once i try and calculate this input, the program crashes. Im fairly new to this finding it confusing as to why this is happening, but im certain its to do with the client side. Thanks

Edit:
Output from Client after crashing :

```
run:
Use the default setting...


  E(x)it from server.
  Press any other key to calculate.  

Enter 1st integer: 5

Enter 2nd integer: 1

Enter your operand: *

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at mathserver.MathClient.main(MathClient.java:80)
```

Output from server after crashing:

```
run:
Math Server is running...
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parsing error!
Math Server is closed...
    at mathserver.MathServer.parseExecution(MathServer.java:52)
    at mathserver.MathServer.execute(MathServer.java:30)
    at mathserver.MathServer.main(MathServer.java:98)
```

EDIT 2: Here is the original MathClient file which i have tried to adapt to allow user input. (program works 100% with this file instead of above MathClient)

```
public class MathClient {
 public static void main(String [] args){
 String hostname = “localhost”;
 int port = 10000;
 if (args.length != 2) {
 System.out.println(“Use the default setting...”);
 }
 else {
hostname = args[0];
 port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
 }
 try {
 // create a socket
 Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, port);
 // perform a simple math operation “12+21”
 BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
 new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
 writer.write(“+:12:21”);
 writer.newLine();
 writer.flush();
 // get the result from the server
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
 new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
 System.out.println(reader.readLine());
 reader.close();
 writer.close();
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
 }
}
```

Comment: What error does it crash with? That's rather important.

Comment: Also, please to to fix your code formatting. It's very difficult to read in parts.

Comment: You should never use catch(Exception), as this will also catch RuntimeExceptions. You more explicit Exceptions, like IOException

Comment: I have added the errors to the bottom of the question

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the input coming into your server is not what is expected. You are splitting on ':', but you are not adding : characters between your operators and operands, so your Double.parseDouble call is failing here:

```
try {
 firstValue = Double.parseDouble(elements[1]);
 secondValue = Double.parseDouble(elements[2]);
 }
 catch(Exception e) {
 throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid arguments!");
 }
```

This is causing your socket to go out of scope, so the socket closes, and that socket closure is causing the exception on your client side.

Be aware that SocketExceptions in many cases, are NOT A PROBLEM, as this functionality allows your reader thread to get out of a `read` call that it's waiting on the socket for.

Also, in your server, where you have

```
public void execute() {
 try {
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
 new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
 // read the message from client and parse the execution
 String line = reader.readLine();
 double result = parseExecution(line);
 // write the result back to the client
 BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
 new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
 writer.write(""+result);
 writer.newLine();
 writer.flush();
 // close the stream
 reader.close();
 writer.close();
```

You do not need to close both the reader and the writer, as closing either one will close the underlying socket. IMO it is clearer to remove these last two lines and just do socket.close();

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this, and for your answer. are you suggesting that adding a colon after every input will result in the program working? i.e    +: , 4: , 3: ? Sorry if that doesnt make sense, im new to this and find it quite confusing atm

Comment: Not the way your example string looks. It seems like from your example string (removing the colons) that if you split on "," rather than ":" it should solve this problem

Comment: Still crashing after changing the split, its saying part of then error is in this piece of code:     // read result from server
  strResult = br.readLine();
System.out.println(strResult);
             break;

Comment: ^^ which is found near the bottom of the MathClient class

Comment: i have included the original MathClient file which runs perfectly, but doesnt allow user input so isnt very useful. I thought this may provide more insight into maybe where i have went wrong in my attempted adaptation of this class.